# В django к пути запроса к статическим файлам добавляется путь строки запроса

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-template

У меня следующая проблема. В бд джанго хранятся пути к картинкам (imagefield) и на главной странице я успешно получаю картинки, подставляя данные из imagefield в django templates. Но когда я пытаюсь запросить фото из страницы к примеру https://127.0.0.1/news, то к прежнему запросу статики [https://127.0.0.1/static/image/какое-то-фото](https://127.0.0.1/static/image/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE) добавляется [https://127.0.0.1/*news*/static/image/какое-то-фото](https://127.0.0.1/*news*/static/image/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE). И соответственно статику не находит. Что делать?

Comment: Вместо относительных ссылок на статику использовать абсолютные, проверьте корректность STATIC_URL